# Refrescar los index de la tabla con JQUERY

Tags: jquery, cshtml

Quiero refrescar mi tabla una vez se elimine un registro de cualquier parte, pero solo me toma el último valor, es decir:

**Por ejemplo:**
Si tengo 5 registros y elimino el 2do, al agregar un nuevo registro me agrega de nuevo el 5to y después el 6to, queda un hueco en la lista del 2do registro que se eliminó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al querer enviar esa información a mi controlador, no envía todos los datos.

Me gustaría que me pudiesen ayudar, para poder refrescar los índices favor, espero tengan una solución para esto

CSHTML

```
<div class="col-sm-2 pt-4">
    <input id="btn_Add" type="button" value="Agregar a la lista" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table id="tableId" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th> <!-- Aqui se imprime el Indice Actual-->
                <th scope="col">Material</th>
                <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                <th scope="col">Unidad de medida</th>
                <th scope="col"></th> <!-- Aqui se imprime el botón Eliminar, despues que agregamos un registro a la tabla-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Este es el Script para Agregar y eliminar de la lista en JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_Add', function () {
        var getMaterialTxt = $('#material option:selected').text();
        var getQuantityTxt = $('#quantity').val();
        var getUnitTxt = $('#unit option:selected').text();

        var getMaterialval = $('#material option:selected').val();
        var getQuantityval = $('#quantity').val();
        var getUnitval = $('#unit option:selected').val();

        var tr = $('<tr>');


        var i = ($(".items").length) / 3;
        $('#tableName tr').each(function (i) {
            var ch = $(this).find('td: eq (4) input').val(); // Toma el valor de la etiqueta de entrada en la i-ésima fila y cuarta columna de la tabla
        });
        tr.append($('<td val="' + i + '">' + i + '</td>'));

        /*--------------------- INFORMACIÓN DE LA TABLA ----------------------*/
        var cat = "Primero seleccione la categoría";
        var empty = "";

        if (getMaterialTxt != cat && getMaterialTxt != empty) {
            tr.append($('<td val="' + getMaterialTxt + '">' + getMaterialTxt + '</td>'));
            tr.append($('<td val="' + getQuantityTxt + '">' + getQuantityTxt + '</td>'));
            tr.append($('<td val="' + getUnitTxt + '">' + getUnitTxt + '</td>'));
            tr.append($('<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar" id="btn_Edit" /></td>'));

        } else {
            Swal.fire(
                'Por favor, elimina el registro vacío',
                "No puede agregar datos vacíos a la lista, de lo contrario tu solicitud no se enviará.",
                'info'
            );
        }

        /*--------------- INPUTS OCULTOS QUE SE ENVIA A BD ----------------------*/
        tr.append($('<td><input type="text" value="' + getMaterialTxt + '" name="OrderLogVM[' + i + '].Producto" class="items" hidden/></td>'));
        tr.append($('<td><input type="text" value="' + getQuantityval + '" name="OrderLogVM[' + i + '].Cantidad" class="items" hidden/></td>'));
        tr.append($('<td><input type="text" value="' + getUnitTxt + '" name="OrderLogVM[' + i + '].Unidad" class="items" hidden/></td>'));
        $('table tbody').append(tr);

        $('#material').val('');
        $('#quantity').val('');
        $('#unit').val('');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#btn_Edit', function () {
        var currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var indx = $(currentTr).prop('index');
        var getMaterialval = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(0).attr('val');
        var getQuantityval = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(1).attr('val');
        var getUnitval = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(2).attr('val');
        $('#selected').val(getMaterialval);
        $('#quantity').val(getQuantityval);
        $('#unit').val(getUnitval);
        currentTr.remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: manejas base de datos para este proyecto?

Comment: Sí, es correcto, esta es solo la parte del front

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes lanzar un trigger cada que hagas el DELETE y re enumeres el campo IDENTITY; como decir, resetear el auto incremental empezando desde el 0.

Comment: No logro comprender como usar el .trigger en ves de .remove, disculpa, soy nuevo en Jquery, agradeceria que pudiese ayudar

Comment: No estoy refiriéndome al uso de JQuery, por eso te digo que puedas hacerlo desde el backend ¿Qué DBMS estás usando? ¿SQL Server, SQLite, MySQL? Desde la base de datos se pueden crear TRIGGERS que se ejecutan luego de haber hecho una instrucción como DELETE (p.ej.), dependiendo de la base de datos puedes resetear el orden autoincrementar del campo IDENTIDAD, esta puede ser una forma para que se actualice automáticamente los campos ID en tu front.

Comment: Ah, no, creo que no me expliqué,

La tabla como tal que quiero refrescar es por parte de la vista, toda la información que se agrega a la vista como una lista, y hasta que no le dé guardar, no se envía esa información a la BDD

Comment: Ya, entonces supongo debe tener un `$(document).on('click', '#btn_Eliminar...` o algo por el estilo, porque en el código que pusiste no se encuentra. ¿Es así?

Comment: Si lo tengo, se llama #btn_Edit y se encuentra hasta la parte de abajo del código donde hago el remove de current index